# Data written to DynamoDB doesn't show on table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I hope someone can help me. I am writing data to dynamoDB which executes without errors, but the data does not display on the dynamoDB table. The table is initiated as follows:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "*table name")

public class AttractionsLibraryDO {
  private String _attractionName;
  private String _attractionCategory;
  private String _attractionCountry;
  private String _attractionDate;
  private String _attractionDescription;
  private Double _attractionEntrance;
  private String _attractionGps;
  private String _attractionLocation;
  private String _attractionPicture;
  private Double _attractionRating;
  private String _attractionToken;
  private Double _attractionVisits;

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Attraction_name")
public String getAttractionName() {
    return _attractionName;
}

public void setAttractionName(final String _attractionName) {
    this._attractionName = _attractionName;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_category")
public String getAttractionCategory() {
    return _attractionCategory;
}

public void setAttractionCategory(final String _attractionCategory) {
    this._attractionCategory = _attractionCategory;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_country")
public String getAttractionCountry() {
    return _attractionCountry;
}

public void setAttractionCountry(final String _attractionCountry) {
    this._attractionCountry = _attractionCountry;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_date")
public String getAttractionDate() {
    return _attractionDate;
}

public void setAttractionDate(final String _attractionDate) {
    this._attractionDate = _attractionDate;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_description")
public String getAttractionDescription() {
    return _attractionDescription;
}

public void setAttractionDescription(final String _attractionDescription) {
    this._attractionDescription = _attractionDescription;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_entrance")
public Double getAttractionEntrance() {
    return _attractionEntrance;
}

public void setAttractionEntrance(final Double _attractionEntrance) {
    this._attractionEntrance = _attractionEntrance;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_gps")
public String getAttractionGps() {
    return _attractionGps;
}

public void setAttractionGps(final String _attractionGps) {
    this._attractionGps = _attractionGps;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_location")
public String getAttractionLocation() {
    return _attractionLocation;
}

public void setAttractionLocation(final String _attractionLocation) {
    this._attractionLocation = _attractionLocation;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_picture")
public String getAttractionPicture() {
    return _attractionPicture;
}

public void setAttractionPicture(final String _attractionPicture) {
    this._attractionPicture = _attractionPicture;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_rating")
public Double getAttractionRating() {
    return _attractionRating;
}

public void setAttractionRating(final Double _attractionRating) {
    this._attractionRating = _attractionRating;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_token")
public String getAttractionToken() {
    return _attractionToken;
}

public void setAttractionToken(final String _attractionToken) {
    this._attractionToken = _attractionToken;
}
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Attraction_visits")
public Double getAttractionVisits() {
    return _attractionVisits;
}

public void setAttractionVisits(final Double _attractionVisits) {
    this._attractionVisits = _attractionVisits;
}
}
```

I write the data to the database as follows:

```
 public class AddAttraction extends AppCompatActivity {
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_attraction);

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), // Context
            "*Cognito identity pool id", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
    );
    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
    final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);
    final AttractionsLibraryDO attractions_Library = new AttractionsLibraryDO();

    SUBMIT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_submit_attraction);
    SUBMIT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
           {
           writeToDynamoDB(attractions_Library, dynamoDBMapper);
           }
    });

}


public Thread writeToDynamoDB(final AttractionsLibraryDO attractions, final DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper) {


        Runnable runnableWrite = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.d("Event:", "Writing to DynamoDB.");
                    attractions.setAttractionCategory("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionRating(int);
                    attractions.setAttractionCountry("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionDate("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionEntrance(int);
                    attractions.setAttractionGps("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionLocation("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionName("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionPicture("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionToken("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionDescription("String");
                    attractions.setAttractionVisits(int);

                    AmazonClientException lastException = null;
                        dynamoDBMapper.save(attractions);
                    Log.d("Event:", "Writing to DynamoDB done.");
                    } catch (final AmazonClientException ex) {
                        Log.d("Error", "Failed saving item : " + ex.getMessage(), ex);

                    }
                }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(runnableWrite);
        t.start();
        return null;

}
}
```

The data does not show up on dynamoDB and both writing to dynamoDB. and writing to dynamoDB done. is logged. Can the issue be that a wrong table name is used (I've double checked this a million times)? I don't know if this is important, but the following line is also logged:

```
 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

I've run out of ideas, please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can't see any problems with what you are doing, it should work. are you sure you are looking in the right AWS region in console?

Comment: also, try adding this line right after saving: `dynamoDBMapper.load(attractions);`, log it and see what you get.

Comment: What is your table name? Why do you have '* table name' in the annotation of attraction class? Is this the real table name?

Comment: Thank you @ketan you steered me in the right direction. So if you have your tables in any other region than US-EAST-1 it defaults to US-EAST-1 even though I initialized the credentialsprovider with EU-WEST-1. To fix this you have to change it using this line ddbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)); after the client was created. I hope it saves someone else a week of their lives. PS. *table name was just a place holder

Comment: great. i am adding the fix as an answer, in case someone falls into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your table is in "eu-west-1", instead of the default "us-east-1", you need to explicitly set the region for your DynamoDB client.

Per your comment, you need to add the following line:

```
ddbClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));
```